# How to flatten Flux<List<T>> to Flux<T>?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Hi my code looks like this:

```
fun mapBatch(batch: List<String>): Mono<List<MyClass>> ...

fun myFun(stream: Flux<String>): Flux<MyClass> {
    return stream
            .bufferTimeout(50, Duration.ofSeconds(60L))
            .flatMap{ batch -> mapBatch(batch) }
            /// now here I would like to get Flux<MyClass> but have Flux<List<MyClass>> 
}
```

How to get the `Flux<T>` from `Flux<List<T>>` ?

Comment: .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `.concatMapIterable` or `.flatMapIterable`.

`Flux#flatMapIterable` is a special operator to "flatten" the item represented as Iterable into a reactive stream of T.

Comment: an example would be fantastic

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten it with `flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)`:

```
fun mapBatch(batch: List<String>): Mono<List<MyClass>> ...

fun myFun(stream: Flux<String>): Flux<MyClass> {
    return stream
            .bufferTimeout(50, Duration.ofSeconds(60L))
            .flatMap{ batch -> mapBatch(batch) }
            .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable) 
}
```